# Why doesn't bash catch the signal from the Java's process.destroy()

Tags: java, linux, bash, process, kill

### A Script For Testing

The script below just hangs until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then it takes two seconds to shut down.  I wrote it to investigate Java's `process.destroy()`

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# dieslowly.sh
bail() {
    echo exiting...
    sleep 2
    echo ...exited

    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
    kill -- -$$
}

trap bail SIGTERM SIGINT

echo "running..."
sleep infinity
```

I think it works because:

- If I run `./dieSlowly.sh` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it waits two seconds and then exits
- If  run `./dieSlowly.sh` and then in a separate terminal run `kill -2 -<pid>`, it waits two seconds then exits

---

### A Process-Handling Test

This (Java) test calls the bash script, and tries to allow it to shut down slowly

```java
void kill_dummy()
{
    // Run the test script
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("./dieSlowly.sh").start();

    // terminate the process, wait for it to stop, then kill it
    DateTime before = new DateTime();

    process.destroy(); // this doesn't seem to do anything

    // Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // rt.exec('kill -9 ' + process.pid);  // this kills it too fast
    // rt.exec('kill -2 -' + process.pid); // this doesn't kill it at all
    // rt.exec('kill -2 ' + process.pid);  // neither does this

    process.waitFor(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    process.destroyForcibly();
    DateTime after = new DateTime();

    // expect it to have taken less than four secongs 
    assert (after.getMillis() - before.getMillis() < 4000);
}
```

I expect the test to take about two seconds--which is how long it takes the script to shut down on its own.

Instead it takes about four seconds.  Using the debugger I have verified that the `destroy()` call has no effect.  This causes `waitFor` to timeout.  `destroyForcibly()` then kills the process with extreme prejudice--which I want to avoid.

#### The Process Tree

If I put a breakpoint on `destroyForcibly()` the command `ps axjf` displays this tree:

```
\_ -zsh
|   \_ /bin/sh /opt/idea-IC-172.4343.14/bin/idea.sh /path/to/my/project
|       \_ idea
|           \_ idea
|               \_ bash ./dieSlowly.sh
|                   \_ sleep infinity
\_ -zsh
|   \_ -zsh
|   \_ bash ./dieSlowly.sh
|       \_ sleep infinity
```

#### My Question

What modifications can I make so that the test triggers the slow-shutdown pathway on the test?

#### Edit

I understand that signals are an OS-specific thing, and the JVM is limited because of its intention to be os-independent.  However, I do successfully kill the process when I run  `kill -9 <pid>` from the JVM, so it seems that it is possible to relay commands to the OS and have it send signals.

Assuming that I can't use `process.destroy()`, then the question becomes:

> Why can I call `kill -9` from the JVM, but not `kill -2`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem, specifically on Debian (while Centos behaves as you'd expect.)

Comment: No, I've moved on from the project where this was relevant, sorry.  That's interesting that it's a Debian-and-not-Centos thing.  I wonder if it's a difference between how these flavors of Linux handle processes, or if the different package managers are installing different Java distributions.

Comment: I think I've found a workaround, although not a complete solution: Removing echo statements in my trap handler allowed Java to gracefully exit the script using process.destroy(). I don't fully understand why -- Possibly output streams being written to after being closed on the Java side is causing something to hang. Again, only an issue for me on Debian :-S.